# Tokenize a string in pl/sql and get unique tokens?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, token, tokenize

I've a requirement to tokenize a string in pl/sql and return only unique tokens. I've seen examples that will tokenize the string, but none that will return unique tokens.

For example the query -

```
select tokenize('hi you person person', ' ') as col1 from dual;
```

should return `TOKEN_LIST('hi','you','person')`

instead of `TOKEN_LIST('hi','you','person','person')`

Answer (score 6):

```
with t as (select 'aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff aaaa' as txt from dual)
-- end of sample data
select DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR (txt, '[^[:space:]]+', 1, level) as word
from t
connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(txt,'[^[:space:]]+'))+1;
```

The above script produces the following result:

```
WORD
dddd
eeee
bbbb
ffff
cccc
aaaa
```

The idea is shamelessly stolen from [OTN Community answer](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/925201?start=0&tstart=0).

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/18224)

Comment: @filmor - Why? OP specifically wanted unique tokens.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that part. For my use-case the order is important, that's why I need to drop `DISTINCT`.